# Load more posts using AJAX based on posts inside WP_Query

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, javascript, pagination

So this is something that I have been battling with for some time now and I can't figure out how to "Load More" posts using AJAX with a combined query.

**Is it possible to AJAX Load more with just the provided IDs? - Also, feel free to scrape the JS completely and show me maybe a better method.**

Basically, here is what I'm attempting to do and it's not working at all:

1. Load only 4 posts at a time from the IDs and then on click, load the next 4 posts.
2. Focus on the `$main_query` variable which has the last WP_Query that completed all the filtering.
3. The `$main_args` in the last arguments returning the following:
   [image]
4. The main WP_Query is the following:
   [image]

---

**HTML**:

```
<?php
$result = FH_Work::getInstance()->fetch_work_items(get_post());
?>

<div class="work-items-container">
    <?php
    echo $result['content'];
    ?>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid view-more-work cnt-pager <?php echo $result['has_pages'] ? '' : 'd-none' ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="eyebrow medium bold dark content" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <span><?php the_field('cta_view_more_text'); ?></span>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn-fh dark btn-primary small evt-view-more-work-items">
                        <i class="custom-icon icon-icon_small_arrow_right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**:

```
public function fetch_work_items($expertise = null)
{
    if ($expertise->post_type != 'expertise') {
        $expertise = null;
    }
    $expertise_id = intval(array_key_exists('expertise_id', $_POST) ? $_POST['expertise_id'] : 0);
    $is_ajax = array_key_exists('is_ajax', $_POST) ? $_POST['is_ajax'] : false;
    $paged = intval(array_key_exists('paged', $_POST) ? $_POST['paged'] : 1);
    $args = [
        'post_status' => ['publish'],
        'post_type' => ['work', FH_Report_Type::CPT_NAME],
        'fields' => 'ids',
    ];
    if (!is_null($expertise) || $expertise_id != 0) {
        $args['meta_query'] = [[
            'key' => 'expertise',
            'value' => '"' . (is_null($expertise) ? $expertise_id : $expertise->ID) . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ]];
    }
    $acf_query = [];
    if (get_field('featured_posts')) {
        $acf_post_ids = get_field('featured_posts', false, false);
        $acf_query = get_posts([
            'post_type' => ['work', FH_Report_Type::CPT_NAME],
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'post__in' => $acf_post_ids,
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
        ]);
        $args['post__not_in'] = $acf_post_ids;
    }
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $main_ids = array_unique(array_merge($acf_query, $wp_query->posts));
    $main_args = [
        'post_type' => ['work', FH_Report_Type::CPT_NAME],
        'post__in' => $main_ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'posts_per_page' => FH_Work::ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        'paged' => $paged
    ];
    $main_query = new WP_Query($main_args);
    $content = '';
    if ($main_query->have_posts()) {
        ob_start();
        get_template_part('template-parts/blocks/work-expertise-filter/work-items-template', null, ['query' => $main_query]);
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    $result = ['content' => $content, 'has_pages' => $main_query->max_num_pages > $paged];

    if ($is_ajax) {
        echo json_encode($result);
        wp_die();
    }

    return $result;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fh_paginate_work_items', [self::getInstance(), 'fetch_work_items']);  
add_action('wp_ajax_fh_paginate_work_items', [self::getInstance(), 'fetch_work_items']);
```

**work-items-template.php**:

```
$query = $args['query'];
$invert_tiles = array_key_exists('meta_query', $query->query);
$counter = $invert_tiles ? 1 : 0; // To define if is left or right template
?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($counter % 2 == 0): ?>
        <!-- Image right -->
        <div class="container showcase img-right" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 img px-0">
                    <div class="imagery-wrap">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="" class="imagery"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $counter++ ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**JavaScript**: Here is what I'm attempting to do, but for some reason I am not able to loop through all the IDs.

```
var WORK_EXPERTISE_MODULE = function ($block) {

    var nextPage = 1;

    function init() {
        $block.find('.evt-view-more-work-items').on('click', paginateWorkItems);
    }

    /**
     * Paginate the work items
     */
    function paginateWorkItems() {
        nextPage++;
        var data = {
            action: 'fh_paginate_work_items',
            is_ajax: true,
            paged: nextPage
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wp_ajax_url.full_url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (!response.hasOwnProperty('content') && !response.hasOwnProperty('has_pages')) {
                    return;
                }
                $block.find('.work-items-container').append(response.content);
                if (response.has_pages === false) {
                    $block.find('.cnt-pager').addClass('d-none');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.evt-init-work-list').each(function (i, ele) {
        (new WORK_EXPERTISE_MODULE($(ele))).init();
    });
});
```

Comment: So you have a static list of post IDs somewhere? If so there's really no reason to specify the rest of your query parameters. I guess I'd just dump the list to inline JS and have the client request the necessary posts from the REST API as needed. Or change your AJAX handler to take in the last post ID as an argument and return the posts which come next.

Comment: It's hard to say what the best solution might be, as based on the information provided this really sort of feels like a [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me - that seems like a pretty unusual way to approach loading a sequence of posts. It could well totally be appropriate - I just struggle to think of the problem which it might solve.

Comment: Basically, at the end of the day - The last wp_query has a list of Post IDs and I would just like to loop through those IDs via AJAx @bosco